# AS3: Addchild dynamically using varying identifier names

Tags: actionscript-3, eval, addchild

Im currently learning as3 but I come from several years of as2 experience, so what I was used to do is attach movieclips using string with a numeric variable to get the right identifier like this and maybe I was thinking about using eval here but of course its not available in as3 so here is what I was doing in as2:

```
currentlevel=1;
myString = "levelMc"+currentlevel;
```

And then of course use the constructed string in "attachMovie" function to get the right clip attached.

```
attachMovie(myString,myString+mydepth,mydepth);
```

But I see in as3 all is about classes and all different so I cant seem to find a way to dynamically get the right class name for the child to be added, is there an actual way to make that possible? because as far as I have gone I see that I should get the class name to make new object and then put that in "addChild" so therefore I cant find a way to pass any kind of dynamically constructed string or element refering my needed clip there, is it still possible?.
Thanks beforehand for any clues =)

EDIT I added the attachmovie call as a clarifying line, I know all you got what I was asking but as I cant find a right approach I prefer to clarify. Additionally I shouldnt have mentioned the "eval" here, sorry, I just can ask my as2 with string usage

EDIT Solved, thanks to you all guys, you saved me, I wish I could give you all kudos because all of your ideas and tips are awesome and really helpful, I marked that answer as correct because it was the one that lead me to getDefinitionByName which is what Im going to use in the end, but as said all tips and ideas to face new as3 world will help me greatly, so as said I wish I could give reputation to you all, thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still can set a name for your object, for instance:

```
var mc : MovieClip;
for (var i : int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   mc = new MovieClip();
   mc.name = "myMc"+ i;
   addChild(mc);
}
```

and you can get a specific child using:

```
this["myMc1"] as MovieClip
```

or

```
this["myMc"+ i] as MovieClip;
```

Comment: Thanks, yes thats great feature I didnt know, thanks for mentioning this =), but I still cant manage to load a specific clip not knowing the clip class beforehand, I mean, of course its going to be inheriting from MovieClip but lets say I dont know the clip class name beforehand it could be from class "level1" or class "level2", "level3" ... so is there a way to get the right class name composing it dinamycally?

Comment: Here you go: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName%28%29

Comment: Thanks, but Im trying to not only get the String containing the class name but what "eval" could have returned, like something I can later put together with "new ...();" and spect the right movieclip to be loaded in run time, is it actually possible?

Comment: Well... if you wanna create a new instance of a class you must know it's name. Can't find one situation where you'd pass something (that's not an Object), get back a class name and from that create a new instance.

My last guess is:

    var className : String = "Acopy3";
    var MyClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(className) as Class;
    var objInstance  = new MyClass();
    addChild(objInstance);

does it help you?

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple array?
Because if you only need to access a set of levels in a ascending numeric fashion, this approach is easier.

```
var levels:Array = new Array();
levels[0] = //your level1 movieclip
levels[1] = //your level2 movieclip
...

function jumpToLevel(index:int):void{
    //remove added levels beforehand
    removeChildren(); //assuming the only children you added to this displaylist 
                      //are levels, otherwise you will need another approach
    addChild(levels[index]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,, you are right, perhaps throuigh this approach its possible to achieve the required result, but as I said Im still learning as3, so I wonder, if I do that as you said, arent the clips loaded in memory beforehand? I mean Im trying to save resources everywhere, so I wonder if I do 

levels[0]=new level0();

isnt it loaded in memory?

Comment: You are right, but @moot hit the nail on the head to solve that problem as well. In Object Oriented Programming Languages such as AS3 you should get used to thinking of Classes in a more abstract way. A Class basically describes the very basics of a level Object, as well as specific information to make it unique from the other Objects from the same Class, like with your levels. How you load that unique information is up to you and another question entirely. Making a separate Class for each one is not the way to go, though.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know I should start thinking about defining a class and use inheritance, polimorphism and all this. Here is like scrolling background in a game, just different direction, a couple of lines each, I wanted it done in 3 lines or so just get the clip needed for the stage, but apparently its more complex now, so either I use switch structure to determine what level is going to be added or else I load them in memory before, but being this a game it requires a lot of resources and fluent constant speed, I dont want to sacrifice resources/decrease speed maybe because of preloaded assets

Answer (score 0):

In AS2, we would store information about instances in instance name - button_0, button_1, etc.  In AS3, you don't need/use instance names for anything other than keeping your code clear to you and to reference stuff you create by hand.

Use arrays to reference your instances.  So, if you're making buttons, you create a button and push it into an array of buttons.  Then just reference it as aMyButtons[i] instead of mcMyButtons["button_" + i]

Here's example code.

```
function fCreateButtons(): void {
    var i: int = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var mcNewButton: McButton = new McButton();
        mcNewButton.x = i * 200;
        mcNewButton.iButtonNumber = i;
        mcNewButton.tMain.text = "About Us";
        mcNewButton.bButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fButtonPress);
        mcNewButton.bButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, fButtonOver);
        mcNewButton.bButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, fButtonOut);

        aButtons.push(mcNewButton);
        }
    }

function fButtonPress(e: MouseEvent): void {
    var iButtonNumber: int = e.currentTarget.parent.iButtonNumber;
    trace("fButtonPress():  iButtonNumber: " + iButtonNumber);
}
```

This is how you'd add the buttons to a holder clip and remove them.

```
mcButtonsHolder.addChild(aButtons[i]);
mcButtonsHolder.removeChild(aButtons[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I see, I didnt know it was done like that, surelly looks a lot different than I was specting, I mean I never thought it could be like this, not really needing the instance name and just having them in an array, well in AS2 one can do similar strategy maybe, just I was used to have their instance names always there of course.

Answer (score 0):

Well as I said above I managed to solve it finally using getDefinitionByName which is the closer I think I can get to "eval", that function managed to bring dinamycally formed class name to be used to call the new clips on run time which is perfect for me, at least make the code cleaner and easier to change if needed. As I said in last edit, thanks a lot to you all who helped, all your tips and ideas will be of great use for me in the as3 time, wish I could give you all reputation, thanks a lot =).